# Using Eloquent for this kind of relationship

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

This is what my table relationship is like:
[image]

One user may have multiple groups. One group may have multiple users. 
One message maybe be only by one user and group.

I have three models in laravel. 
User,Message, and Group. And my pivot table is mssg_group which stores which user sent which message to which group. 
(if this design is incorrect, do tell me the better way).

How do I write relationships to access all messages before a certain time by supplying a groupID?

Answer (score 1):

I think your searching for the hasManyThrough relationship.

You need a Group model with a relationship to messages. See the [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through) for more info.

```
/** 
* app/Group.php
*/

public function messages(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Message','App\MessageGroup');
}
```

In your Message Group Model you need to create the messages relation.

```
/*
* app/MessageGroup.php
*/
protected $table = "mssg_grp";

public function messages(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Message','id','mssg_id');
}
```

In your Message model be sure to define your custom table name.

```
/*
* app/Message.php
*/
class Message extends Model {
    protected $table = 'mssg';
}
```

In your controller you can eager load the date requirement.

```
$group_messages = Group::where('id', $group_id)->with(function($query)
  {
    return $query->where('created_at','>',$date);
  })->get()
```

I haven't tested it, so this may need to be tweaked a little bit, but it should get you close to where you want to be. I haven't address retrieving users, but it should be nearly the same as getting the messages synced up. Let me know if this helps.